# Weird interaction between xy and babel

Tags: babel, xy-pic, dvips

Recently, I am having a weird interaction between xy and babel. When I run latex and dvips, the resulting ps file is corrupted and I cannot do ps2pdf. I am pretty sure it used to worked one year ago. Also, compilation with pdflatex works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[dvips]{xy}

\begin{document}

toto

\end{document}
```

Weirdly, it works by replacing `\usepackage[french]{babel}` by `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}`. I'd still like to understand why. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome. It used to work with TeX Live 2019, but the error is the same from TL 2020 on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails when `:` is made active, even without `french`. `xy` hasn’t changed in years, thus leaving either the `babel` core or LaTeX as the possible culprit. I’m not sure what has changed, but here is a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\AtBeginDvi{\shorthandoff{:}} % Add this line
\usepackage[dvips]{xy}

\begin{document}

toto

\end{document}
```

Comment: has something moved between  AtBeginDvi and AtBeginDocument? the relative timing of catcode changes in those seems to be an issue here.

Comment: `\AtEndDocument` doesn't work if the document has more than one page, as then the hook is after `\AtBeginDvi` where the problematic code is executed. You need `\AtBeginDvi{\shorthandoff{:}}` (before loading xy).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Edited.